# Error Read .txt from sdcard insert into EditText

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-sdcard

I made an android program where we(user) can set the id etc. from Edit Text and then that value will be saved into .txt file in sdcard. I already can do that (make a .txt file in sdcard. now I'm trying to read that .txt file in other activities in my application and insert that value in edit text there when this activities start/begin.. I need that so I can set for example "id" just one time in my application,, and then everytime user makes a form entries data, some data that set before for example "id" already insert into edit text in entries activities there.. when i'm trying to read value from .txt(file that i build before in other Activity) and want to insert that value into EditText when Activity started, i got an error something like this 
**"activity unable to bla.. bla.. bla.." *"java.lang.null.pointerexception"***
please help me what i miss in my code, thanks

this is my code in Activities when i'm trying to read .txt file :

```
package com.asrimobile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Email extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    //inisilisasi elemen-elemen pada layout
    private Button Send;
    private EditText Subject;
    private EditText Message;
    private TextView tv_attach;
    private ImageButton Attachment;
    private EditText edTo_email;

    String file_path;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    int columnindex;
    //Uri URI = null;

    //inisialisasi kontroller/Data Source
    private DBDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.email);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"myconfig2.txt");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        edTo_email.setText(text);
        edTo_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to_email);

        Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        Attachment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_attachment);
        Subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        Message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        tv_attach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_attach_id);

        Attachment.setOnClickListener(this);
        Send.setOnClickListener(this);

        // instanstiasi kelas DBDataSource
        dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);

        //membuat sambungan baru ke database
        dataSource.open();
    }   
    String to_email = edTo_email.getText().toString();

    //KETIKA Tombol Submit Diklik
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.button_attachment:
                openGallery();
                break;

            case R.id.button_send:
                //String surat3 = edTo_email.getText().toString();
                String surat1 = Subject.getText().toString(); 
                String surat2 = Message.getText().toString(); 
                //File pngDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"");

                //if (!pngDir.exists())
                //{
                //  pngDir.mkdirs();
                //}
                //File pngfile=new File(pngDir, "asri.xls");
                //Uri pngUri =Uri.fromFile(pngfile);
                //kirim email
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                //need this prompt email clients only
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
                //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {surat3});
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, surat1);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, surat2);
                //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
                //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
                //emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

                ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
                fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/asri.xls");
                fileList.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/kk.png");
                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
                {
                    File fileIn = new File(fileList.get(i));
                    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                    uris.add(u);
                }
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                //String[] filePaths = new String[] {"sdcard/entri_pengajuan.csv"};
                //for (String file : filePaths)
                //{
                //  File fileIn = new File(file);
                //  Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                //  uris.add(u);
                //}
                //emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

                //if (URI != null) {
                //    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
                //}

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
                break;
        }
    }
    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        PICK_IMAGE);

    }   

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               /**
                * Get Path
                */
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
               String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
               file_path = cursor.getString(columnindex);
               tv_attach.setText(file_path);
               //URI = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path);
               cursor.close();
               Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
               File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
               File f = new File (sdcard, "kk.png");
               FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line to read file from sdcard and set it to edittext

```
File logFile = new File("sdcard/text.txt");
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(logFile);
BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(fIn));
 String aDataRow = "";
 String aBuffer = "";
  while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
   aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";}
   edittext.settext(aBuffer);
```